# using Expressjs as a proxy for cross domain ajax calls

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, cross-domain, express

I am developing a site which is fully external API based. I do not have any server side logic. All the data would be fetched from an external API. The back end server is used for asset management and routing predominantly. It has been decided to have `nodejs` running on backend along with `expressjs`. I wanna know what modifications are necessary to be done in the expressjs routing to route (as a proxy) all the cross domain ajax API call coming from the browser to the appropriate site and route back the json data to the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a little proxy that routed calls to an API, but I eventually dropped it so this may need a bit more work. The basic idea is:

- Ajax can't make cross-domain requests in every browser
- You have an external API at `http://api.example.com/`
- Your application lives in `http://foo.com/`
- You want to proxy everything that goes to `http://foo.com/api/*` to `http://api.example.com/*`

The best way to do it is to use [Streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html). You want to filter all requests to `foo.com/api/` and then make a request to `api.example.com` based on the received URL. You'll then have 4 objects:

- The request made to `foo.com`
- The response object for that request
- The request made to `api.example.com`
- The response from the API server

All of those are Streams. The first and last are readable streams and the others are writable streams. So what you want to do is write whatever comes from the readable stream to the writable stream. You do that with the readable stream's `pipe` method. This looks like:

```
requestFromBrowser.pipe(requestToAPI(function (responseFromAPI) {
  responseFromAPI.pipe(responseToBrowser);
}));
```

You still need to write headers by hand and possibly deal with other details. This is what my rudimentary code looked like. It's middleware for Connect/Express.

```
var http = require('http');

exports.proxy = function (prefix) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    var options = {
      port: 3000,
      // the server receives a url like http://foo.com/api/(*)
      // send the proxy only (*)
      path: req.url.substr(prefix.length),
      // headers and the method need to be written explicitely
      method: req.method,
      headers: req.headers
    };
    if (req.url.indexOf(prefix) === 0) {
      req.pipe(http.request(options, function (proxy) {
        res.writeHead(proxy.statusCode, proxy.headers);
        proxy.pipe(res);
      }).on('error', next));
    } else {
      next();
    }
  };
};
```

I'd recommend you to look for a module that already does this. There's probably more than one in the NPM registry. Also, read more on Streams since they're awesome for writing proxies and the like.

---